# How to go about implementing Texting / SMS / MMS into C# application

Tags: c#, sms, mms

I am looking to integrate texting SMS/MMS into my current application. I have been looking around but I cannot find anything that seems to meet my needs. Any advice would be excellent.

Here are my requirements:

- Must have the support for QR codes as an option, not every text will have this
- Static long code
- Ability to purchase multiple short codes or keywords with shared short code
- 2 way messaging
- C# API A HUGE plus

Answer (score 2):

Twilio.com has a great service with REST services and a C# wrapper here https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp

Comment: Twilio does not yet support Short codes. Yes, coming soon, as many say, but soon is not what I can tell my clients... thank you for reply

Comment: they are in beta testing now and you can request access... http://www.twilio.com/sms/short-codes

Comment: Looking more for a proven track record, not beta, I do not have time to play tester at this time, on top of that, I cannot get anyone on the phone there at this time.

Comment: I work there. Call me 415-236-0995 or email jsheehan@twilio.com. Our short code API does not need technical testing, we just haven't opened it up yet. Get in touch and we can talk about it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply John. I will give you a call!

Comment: twilio looks like a great service but they do not support QRcodes over MMS at this time

Answer (score 1):

I have had good luck with ClickATell.  It's all commodity services now days anyway.  I wouldn't worry too much about a C# specific API.  There isn't much involved with interfacing with SMS providers, usually it's a straight forward web service API and C# makes short work of generating proxy classes for you.  Anything else specific you're looking for?  SLA stuff perhaps?

Comment: All text management must be done through our application, that is why an API is needed. Thank you for reply I also do not think they support Qr Codes, also very expensive.